# Auto-generating tables using etoolbox

Tags: tables, automation, etoolbox

I have a particular problem which I am trying to solve using `etoolbox`, but I can't figure out how. What I'm trying to do is to auto-generate a table based on information from a previous table. This is best explained with an example:

```
\newcounter{numc}
\setcounter{numc}{0}
\newcolumntype{n}{>{\thenumc.}r<{\addtocounter{numc}{1}}}
% This is simply a column displaying the row number.

\newrobustcmd{\push}[1]{\listadd{\numcount}{\thenumc} \listadd{\ncom}{#1}}
% This command may have to be defined differently, depending on the missing code below.

\begin{xtabular}{ n l l }
  & row1,col2    & row1,col3 \\
  & row2,col2    & row2,col3 \\ \push{Comment for row 2.}
  & row3,col2    & row3,col3 \\ 
  & row4,col2    & row4,col3 \\ \push{Comment for row 4.}
  & row5,col2    & row5,col3 \\ \push{Comment for row 5.}
\end{xtabular}

\begin{xtabular}{ r l }
% The code for auto-generating the second table goes here.
% The first column is supposed to be the values in the numcount list, minus 1.
% The second column is supposed to be the text in the ncom list.
\end{xtabular}
```

So the output is intended to be as follows:

Table 1:

```
1.   row1,col2   row1,col3
2.   row2,col2   row2,col3
3.   row3,col2   row3,col3
4.   row4,col2   row4,col3
5.   row5,col2   row5,col3
```

Table 2:

```
2.   Comment for row 2.
4.   Comment for row 4.
5.   Comment for row 5.
```

However, I can't find a good solution for the missing code in the second table. The code should generate the first column from the first list (`numcount`), and the second column from the second list (`ncom`).

Do you have any suggestions to how I can solve this?

Answer (score 7):

As already commented, `\listadd` won't work because the `tabular` environment is a local scope, so the lists are only defined inside your table. Therefore, we need the global version `\listgadd`. *And* then you add `\thenumc` to a list, but `\thenumc` doesn't get expanded until the list itself is used, which is the reason we will ned `\listxadd` here (`\listeadd` is not global).
(The same applies for the `\appto` macro I actually use.)

I did not used `etoolbox`' lists but a primitive macro. Furthermore, I defined only one macro where the actual contents are separated by `/`, I need only to loop over *one* list now.

The counter `intXI` is used to detect the first `\push` and the last line for the `\mytable` macro.

I also pushed the `\push` command before the `\\` macro, because

- no confusion about `\thenumc` (the `\push` macro falls in the `n` column of the next line)
- no otherwise empty line at the end of the table.

#### Mini Solution

In this simple case we could use

```
\ifnum\value{intXI}=1\relax%
  \xappto\mytable{\thenumc & #1}%
\else%
  \xappto\mytable{\noexpand\\\thenumc & #1}%
\fi%
```

in the `\push` macro without the use of a loop.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcounter{numc}\newcounter{intXI}
\newcolumntype{n}{>{\stepcounter{numc}\thenumc.}r}

\newrobustcmd{\push}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{intXI}%
    \ifnum\value{intXI}=1\relax%
      \xappto\mylist{\thenumc/{#1}}%
    \else%
      \xappto\mylist{,\thenumc/{#1}}%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ n l l }
  & row1,col2    & row1,col3 \\
  & row2,col2    & row2,col3 \push{Comment for row 2.} \\
  & row3,col2    & row3,col3 \\
  & row4,col2    & row4,col3 \push{Comment for row 4.} \\
  & row5,col2    & row5,col3 \push{Comment for row 5.} \\
\end{tabular}
\foreach \contentn/\contentt in \mylist {%
    \addtocounter{intXI}{-1}%
    \ifnum0=\value{intXI}\relax
      \xappto\mytable{%
          \contentn & \contentt%
      }%
    \else
      \xappto\mytable{%
          \contentn & \contentt\noexpand\\%
      }%
    \fi%
}%

\begin{tabular}{ r l }
    \mytable
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested in an alternative solution that doesn't use `etoolbox` but `xparse` and the LaTeX3 environment, here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,xparse}
\newcounter{numc}

\newcolumntype{n}{>{\stepcounter{numc}\thenumc.}r}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{xtabular}{ m }
 {
  \seq_gclear:N \g_eiterorm_pushes_seq
  \setcounter{numc}{0}
  \begin{tabular}{n #1}
 }
 {
  \end{tabular}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\push}{ m }
 {
  \eiterorm_push:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printcomments} { }
 {
  \begin{tabular}{rl}
  \seq_use:Nnnn \g_eiterorm_pushes_seq { \\ } { \\ } { \\ }
  \end{tabular}
 }
\seq_new:N \g_eiterorm_pushes_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \eiterorm_push:n #1
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_eiterorm_pushes_seq { \thenumc. \exp_not:n { & #1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{xtabular}{ l l }
  & row1,col2    & row1,col3 \\
  & row2,col2    & row2,col3 \push{Comment for row 2.} \\
  & row3,col2    & row3,col3 \\ 
  & row4,col2    & row4,col3 \push{Comment for row 4.} \\
  & row5,col2    & row5,col3 \push{Comment for row 5.} 
\end{xtabular}

\bigskip

\printcomments

\end{document}
```

Note that `\push` should go *before* the terminal `\\` because otherwise the last row will initiate a new row which would have the initial number and empty contents and *no* final `\\` should appear.

The idea is that `\push` adds to a sequence that is later used by `\printcomments`.

[image]